# Java: Prevent items from being added to UI as duplicates

Tags: java, swing, loops, button

Every time I click a tab `tab3`, it reloads a list `listOfFiles`, then adds a button to the tab for each item in the list. How can I get it to not keep adding  the same buttons again each time I click the tab? Note: The list may be modified between each click.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        JButton btnTemp2 = new JButton("Load: " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        tab3.add(btnTemp2);
        tab3.revalidate();
    }
}
```

**Whats happening (for example, after two clicks):**

(button) Load: MyFile

(button) Load: MyFile2

(button) Load: MyFile

(button) Load: MyFile2

**What I want (after any number of clicks):**

(button) Load: MyFile

(button) Load: MyFile2

Comment: Did you clear the List before reloading the file list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all elements with `tab3.removeAll()` method. So, after each click, firstly call this method and then add the buttons.

```
tab3.removeAll();
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        JButton btnTemp2 = new JButton("Load: " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        tab3.add(btnTemp2);
    }
}
tab3.revalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your `File` references in a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) rather than a `List` or array.